# How can I do classification with a float data type after normalization?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn

I am working with a data set labeled Adult and I am trying to run a KNN on a few of the columns I have made into a new data Frame and normalized a couple of the columns. I am getting a `ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'` error when trying to run

```
clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

After researching the error on line it seems that I need to use a label encoder on my data after I have normalized it, because it is now a `float` rather than an `int` but I am having trouble with using the label encoder. The code I am using is:

```
import numpy as np ##Import necassary packages
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
from sklearn.preprocessing import *
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
url2="http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data" #Reading in Data from a freely and easily available source on the internet
Adult = pd.read_csv(url2, header=None, skipinitialspace=True) #Decoding data by removing extra spaces in cplumns with skipinitialspace=True
##Assigning reasonable column names to the dataframe
Adult.columns = ["age","workclass","fnlwgt","education","educationnum","maritalstatus","occupation",  
                 "relationship","race","sex","capitalgain","capitalloss","hoursperweek","nativecountry",
                 "less50kmoreeq50kn"]
Adult.loc[Adult.loc[:, "race"] == "Amer-Indian-Eskimo", "race"] = "Other" #consolidating catagorical data in the race column

Adult.loc[:,"race"].value_counts().plot(kind='bar') #plotting the consolidated catagorical data in the race column
plt.title('race after consolidation')
plt.show()

Adult.loc[:, "White"] = (Adult.loc[:, "race"] == "White").astype(int) #One hot encoding the catagorical/creating new categorical data in the race column
Adult.loc[:, "Black"] = (Adult.loc[:, "race"] == "Black").astype(int)
Adult.loc[:, "Asian-Pac-Islander"] = (Adult.loc[:, "race"] == "Asian-Pac-Islander").astype(int)
Adult.loc[:, "Other"] = (Adult.loc[:, "race"] == "Other").astype(int)

Adult.loc[:,"Other"] #Verifying One-hot encoding for Other column

Adult = Adult.drop("race", axis=1) #removing the obsolete column "race"

Minage = min(Adult.loc[:,"age"])  #MinMax normalizing the age column
Maxage = max(Adult.loc[:,"age"])
MinMaxage = (Adult.loc[:,"age"] - Minage)/(Maxage - Minage)

Minhours = min(Adult.loc[:,"hoursperweek"])  #MinMax ormalizing the hoursperweek column
Maxhours = max(Adult.loc[:,"hoursperweek"])
MinMaxhours = (Adult.loc[:,"hoursperweek"] - Minhours)/(Maxhours - Minhours)

df2 = pd.DataFrame() #creating a dataframe to plot the normilized data
df2.loc[:,0] = Adult.loc[:, "White"] #filling the data frame
df2.loc[:,1] = MinMaxage
df2.loc[:,2] = MinMaxhours

df2.columns = ["White","MinMaxage","MinMaxhours"]

X = np.array(df2.drop(['MinMaxhours'], 1))
y = np.array(df2['MinMaxhours'])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)
clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

accuracy = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
print(accuracy)

clf.predict(X_test)
y_test
```

Could someone help me out with how to label encode the data so I can perform Knn on the data? I have looked it up on the sklearn site and different examples, but am still having trouble using it on my dataset. I receive the error message when trying to fit the data running `clf.fit(X_train, y_train)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a regression problem instead of a classification problem. You are trying to predict the MinMaxHours variable, which is a real number. If you are trying to predict real number you should use the regression version of the Neirest neighbor algorithm. The following code should work in order to get a prediction.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
clf = KNeighborsRegressor()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_test_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: I have considered that. However after normalizing data when trying to run a classification problem, I will still run into the same issue correct? or is it not common to use normalization with classification?

Comment: It's not possible to do classification on floating data. What is it exactly that you want to predict? You can predict the probability that the nr of hours is in a certain category e.g. between 35-40 hours, this is a classification problem. Or you could try to get as close to the exact amount of hours by making a regression model. Then your output will be a real number instead of a probability.

Comment: Ok, I did a classification model without using normalized data and as you would expect the accuracy was poor. But yes I am trying to predict the number of hours based on 'age' and 'white.' I just though there would be a way to run the classification model again with normalized data.

Comment: Looking at other example can I create a classification model that uses float types however the predicted value is not a float type?

Comment: Yes that's correct. You can use float types as inputs for a classification model, however the predicted value can only be a boolean (1 or 0) if you're trying to predict between two classes. e.g. you are trying to predict whether the animal in a picture is a cat or a dog. Besides a boolean the predicted value can also be an integer if there are more than two classes (0=dog, 1=cat, 2=bird, etc....). Hope this clarifies it!